# why unix can copy files in use while windows can't?

Tags: unix

Why can I copy some files in Mac when in use, like PDFs open in preview.app, or even copy some applications to another when opening it?

What will happen if I edit the text in copying ? Why cannot windows do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file system works differently in linux, applications in linux don’t lock exclusive access to files as often as they do on Windows.
you can modified files in windows while they locked with Third-party software like: Unlocker [enter link description here](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

Comment: But if there is no file lock, how can UNIX ensure that the file I copied is the same as the one in using ?

Comment: It can't, and it won't, @Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

When your file is open, temporary file is created with the same name with a tilde at the end of the filename like: test.txt --> test.txt~ (you can see that when you type ls -l in terminal UNIX
now UNIX ensure that the file you are copied is the same as the one you using.

Comment: This is simply not true. *Some* programs do it that way, but it is not even the norm. Certainly, all programs that just *read* the file don't do that.